# Selecting checkbox in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, watir

I am new to automation and am learning some of the basics. How can I select this checkbox using ruby?

```
<a href="/search?f[0]=pax%3A2&amp;f[1]=destination%3A65#lb-content-tabs" rel="nofollow" class="facetapi-inactive facetapi-checkbox-processed lb_general_loading_spinner-processed" data-search-text-english="Turkey">Turkey <strong>(3)</strong><span class="element-invisible">Apply Turkey filter</span></a>
```

Comment: I should mention that the page contains several of these checkboxes. The only way to distinguish between them is the country which in this example is Turkey.

Answer (score 1):

You can see from the tag that it is actually an `a` element. This means it is actually a link. A checkbox would be an `input` element with `type="checkbox"`.

Given that the country is the unique attribute about the element, you have a couple of options. The best solution is likely to locate the element using the `data-search-text-english` attribute:

```
browser.link(data_search_text_english: 'Turkey').click
```

You could also use the link text. However, this link's text includes other text, eg the `(3)`. This means that you will need to match the text using a regular expression (ie to do a partial match).

```
browser.link(text: /Turkey/).click
```

Comment: I was close to answering it. I was using browser.checkbox

Thanks for this :)